# When I try to import cv in python, some errors occur. How to fix it

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

```
import cv
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
from cv2.cv import *
 ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset
```

The fist time when I import the module cv, some errors occurred .
I change the pythonpath to the opencv lib, then try again ,some different errors above occur.

My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04. Python version(2.7.6)

Comment: How did you install OpenCV, OpenCV-Python, and Pango and the rest of its Gtk/GNOME friends?

Comment: (I ask because the most obvious possibility is that you installed a binary package for either OpenCV or its Python bindings that was built against a different version/build-configuration/whatever of Pango than you have.)

Comment: I have not installed Pango. I download opencv from http://opencv.org/, and then install it.What is OpenCV-Python? I can only find opencv-helpers (0.1).

Comment: when I try to install opencv or pango, it shows that "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement ***".       --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                  $ pip install opencv
Downloading/unpacking opencv
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement opencv
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for opencv
Storing debug log for failure in /home/kdh/.pip/pip.log

Comment: By "… and then install it", you mean you followed the instructions [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation), making sure you had all the required packages, and then did the `cmake`-based build and install?

Comment: Sorry about the OpenCV-Python confusion; current versions of OpenCV automatically install the Python bindings if they find Python and NumPy dev libraries, so you don't need an extra step (at least if you're installing from source).

Comment: Meanwhile, definitely do not change the `PYTHONPATH` to include the directory where you unpacked OpenCV; that will probably cause a whole slew of problems. The `sudo make install` step should put everything it needs into your Python's `dist-packages` in the proper way (and it apparently did, because that's where the file that raised the exception lives…). So, that isn't your problem, and trying to fix it will just break worse things.

Comment: I mean I have followed the instruction.  I install all the required package except the optional. 
> I have changed the pythonpath back. 
The original error occur is showed below.

Comment: >>> import cv 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kdh/share/Enthought/environment/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: No module named cv2.cv

Comment: @abarnert  
When I use c++ to compile a demo file, it compiled successfully. It seems that the problem is not about the opencv but the python.

Comment: Try this; In your opencv installation folder, there a file `cv2.pyd` located in `opencv/build/python`, copy and paste it in `Python27/lib/site-packages`

Comment: which opencv version is it ? the arcane cv2.cv does no more exist in 3.0

Comment: @berak  the version is 3.0. What can I do for that.

Comment: I have do that but of no use. @ Soma

Comment: abarnert said that I couldn  not use cv  and  change the PYTHONPATH.@berak @Soma

Comment: After I change the PYTHONPATH， another error occur as below.

Comment: ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset

Comment: But I don't know what happen. Can any body tell me ?

Comment: you will have to `import cv2` . the old cv module was removed

Comment: But import cv2 also have the same problems.@berak

Comment: ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset

Comment: I found that there is no any file name cv2.py. I could only find cv2.pyd,cv2.cpp and cv2.so@berak

Comment: hi ! i met the same problem when i try to install python-opencv in ubuntu.

Comment: Anyone figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

Install the python dependency via the apt command, rebuild your opencv module and try import

```
import cv2
```

And make sure your python can refer to your default site-packages folder where you have kept the required python files or libraries

Add these lines in the code:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

or before running the python command in bash move to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages directory. This is a work around if you don't want to add any thing to the code.

OR

try adding the following line in ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PATH
```